# Solution code not working for javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated error

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

This might be a duplicate but my issue is more about why my solution code is not working. 
I am facing the javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated error. So I am using this piece of code to fix this issue : http://javaskeleton.blogspot.com/2010/07/avoiding-peer-not-authenticated-with.html

In my constructor I am calling it as :

```
 this.httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    if(port == 443) {
        this.targetHost = new HttpHost(host, port, "https");
        this.httpclient = MyClass.wrapClient(httpclient);
    } else {
        this.targetHost = new HttpHost(host, port);
    }
```

the code from the site looks like this:

```
    public static DefaultHttpClient wrapClient(DefaultHttpClient base) {
    try {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        X509HostnameVerifier verifier = new X509HostnameVerifier() {

            //@Override
            public void verify(String string, SSLSocket ssls) throws IOException {
            }

            //@Override
            public void verify(String string, X509Certificate xc) throws SSLException {
            }

            //@Override
            public void verify(String string, String[] strings, String[] strings1) throws SSLException {
            }

            //@Override
            public boolean verify(String string, SSLSession ssls) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
        SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);
        ssf.setHostnameVerifier(verifier);
        ClientConnectionManager ccm = base.getConnectionManager();
        SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
        sr.register(new Scheme("https", ssf, 443));
        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, base.getParams());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

However it still gives me the same "peer not authenticated error". I have commented the @Override cause it gives me an error saying : "the method verify(String string, SSLSocket ssls) of type new X509HostnameVerifier(){} must override a superclass method.

I have tried using different code to replace this but non of them seem to work.
Any suggestion and help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The `X509TrustManager` code is both insecure and incorrect. It isn't permitted to return null from getAcceptedIssuers().

Comment: Any suggestions on how this can be fixed then?